# ionic 2 ion-radio error with loop

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a trouble with ionic 2 ion-radio.

The idea is: the component gets data from a service that uses HTTP and assign the value to the `data` property within `ngOnInit` but the radio button cannot be selected.

Template:

```
<ion-list class="rooms" padding radio-group>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let r of data?.rooms">
       <ion-label >{{ r?.name }}</ion-label>
       <ion-radio checked="{{ selectedRoom == r?.id }}" value="{{ r?.id }}"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

import { BookConfirmPage } from '../bookconfirm/bookconfirm';
import { RoomDetailPage } from '../roomdetail/room';

import { HotelService } from '../../providers/hotel/hotelservice';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-hotel-detail',
  templateUrl: 'hotel.html',
  providers: [HotelService]
})
export class HotelDetailPage implements OnInit {

  public data;
  public selectedRoom: number;

  constructor(
    private navCtrl: NavController,
    private hotelServ: HotelService,
    private navParams: NavParams
    ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // u need a interface to make data readable and consistent.
    // this really unrecomended. for learn only.
    let id = this.navParams.get('id');
    let idRoom = this.navParams.get('idRoom');

    this.hotelServ.get(id).then(res => {
      this.data = res;
      //console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

    this.selectedRoom = idRoom;
  }

  showBookConfirm(id) {
    console.log(this.selectedRoom)
    this.navCtrl.push(BookConfirmPage, { 'id': id });
  }

  showRoomDetail(id) {
    this.navCtrl.push(RoomDetailPage, { 'id': id });
  }

}
```

Edited:
This just Interpolation issue in my code. just change the template. `[valye]="r?.id"`

Comment: Is your issue fixed? As does your edit suggests. If it isn't it might be quite easy to fix. If it is, please answer your question and accept it, will prevent unneccessary attention :)

Comment: Ya, and how to answer my question and accept it ? there is no solved mark here. [Edited] okay i found it. XD and wait for 2 days. :) thanks for ur attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change

```
<ion-list class="rooms" padding radio-group>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let r of data?.rooms">
    <ion-label >{{ r?.name }}</ion-label>
    <ion-radio checked="{{ selectedRoom == r?.id }}" value="{{ r?.id }}"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

into

```
<ion-list class="rooms" padding radio-group [(ngModel)]="selectedRoom">

  <ion-card class="room-card" *ngFor="let r of data?.rooms">
    <ion-card-content>
      <div class="left">
        <ion-radio [value]="r?.room_id"></ion-radio>
      </div>
      <div class="right" (click)="showRoomDetail(r?.room_id)">
        <ion-card-title>
          {{ r?.name }} {{ r?.room_id }}
        </ion-card-title>
        <p color="warning">&nbsp;Rp. {{ r?.cost }}</p>
      </div>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card> 

</ion-list>
```

cause this just interpolation issue, not from ionic but from my code

Comment: just curious. You're setting `checked="selectedRoom....."`  but `selectedRoom` is only set upon `ngOnInit()` and not changed anywhere. Shouldn't the `selectedRoom` change based on what room/radio button is selected?

Comment: Ah okay, if you need help just let me know :)